# Laravel 7.28.3: Supervisor Throwing Error on Execution of New Job **PHP Fatal error: method_exists()**

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, supervisord

I have created a new job in **laravel 7.28.3** and dispatch it from controller.
I am using Database as Queue Connection and its dispatching absolutely fine (Confirmed by checking in the database jobs table).

Job creation command:

```
php artisan make:job NewJob
```

When Supervisor tries to run the job it throws following error.

**PHP Fatal error:  method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "App\Jobs\NewJob" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition**

If i initiate the queue:work manually it works fine and show me results of job using following command:

```
{PROJECT_PATH}/artisan queue:work --tries=3 --timeout=0 --queue=default
```

Steps Done So far:

- Reloaded Supervisorctl
- Restarted Supervisor Service
- Executed composer dump-autoload

**Note: Old Job working absolutely fine.**

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $message = "Test";
        echo $message;
        dd($message);
    }
}
```

Dispatched from Controller

```
dispatch(new NewJob());
```

Supervisor Configuration

```
[program:Notifications]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php {PROJECT_PATH}/artisan queue:work --tries=3 --timeout=0 --queue=default
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile={PROJECT_PATH}/storage/logs/notifications-worker.log
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue by configuring Laravel Horizon and it is working like a charm :)

Comment: can you share what you did exactly? I'm experiencing a similar issue and am also using Horizon.